# Raid5 + LVM2 + grub2: final config and boot

Tags: debian, grub2, lvm, raid5

- I have a one disk, no RAID, no LVM system based on Debian Squeeze (my old system).
- I created a RAID array (RAID 5, 4 HDDs) with `mdadm` (my new system).
- I installed LVM2 on the new system and created several LVs.
- I migrated the folders (/,/boot,/home,/var/,/tmp,/usr) of the old system in the respective LVs (lv_root,lv_boot,lv_home,lv_var,lv_tmp,lv_usr) by using `rsync`.
- Note that my `boot` is in LVM, not outside.

How do I proceed for the following tasks (I didn't find any good tutorials for my level of knowledge):

- Once the RAID array is created, how can I build a `mdadm.conf` file on the new system?
- How can I create a `fstab` file on the new system
- How can I install Grub2 in `/boot` and configure the four disks in order to boot from any?

After these tasks, I should be able to shutdown my machine, remove the HDD with the old system, restart the machine and the new system should boot.

Comment: So the new system is a installation from scratch (Debian Wheezy?)? What folders did you migrate from the old system - just `/home` and stuff like that, or also parts of the system itself (`/usr`, ...)? If it's an installation from scratch, the Debian installer should have taken care of the tasks that you list.

Comment: see my new text according to your question. It's not a scratch.

Answer (score 3):

So you're inside a rescue system now? You need mount all these LVs somewhere, for example to `/mnt/target`:

- lv_root -> `/mnt/target/`
- lv_boot -> `/mnt/target/boot`
- lv_home -> `/mnt/target/home`
- ...

Then you need to bind-mount the kernel filesystems:

```
for i in proc sys run dev; do mount --bind /$i /mnt/target/$i; done
```

Now you can change into this "dead" system with `chroot`:

```
chroot /mnt/target
```

You are now inside the system, as if you had booted into it; that is, `/` is now no longer the old `/` from your rescue system, but the root LV.

Create the `mdadm.conf`:

```
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

Check it manually with an editor to see if everythings OK.

Create the `device.map` for grub:

```
grub-mkdevicemap
```

Check that manually too. Install grub to all disks (put in the correct disk names here):

```
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install /dev/sdb
...
```

Manually adapt you `/etc/fstab` so that all LVs are mounted to their correct mount points.

Regenerate the grub config and the initramfs:

```
update-grub
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Very good info for me. I am inside the old system, not a rescue system. I didn't migrate the content of the /sys et /proc folders. Shall I do it ? Chroot was missing in my knowledge ! How can I terminate this function ? Before the device.map creation, I suppose that I must install or verify that Grub2 is in the boot folder, correct ?

Comment: @Bertaud It's usually wise to do migrations like these from some kind of rescue system, because a) you're guaranteed that the old system won't change during or after you've copied the files to the new system (for example, if you have a mail server running, it might accept an incoming mail after you've already copied the mail spool. This mail is lost when you switch to the new system) and b) you can access the whole filesystem without having to worried about overmounted folders like `/dev`.

Comment: "I didn't migrate the content of the /sys et /proc folders. Shall I do it?" - no, do not try to copy the *contents* of `/proc` and `/sys`, because these are virtual filesystems. You really don't want to try to copy files like `/proc/kcore` ;). Instead, create them as empty folders in the target filesystem, and then mount-bind them so you can successfully `chroot` into it.

Comment: Ok. I will try tomorow because it's 01:00 am ;-) I appreciated your explanation. Gute Nacht.

Comment: my mdadm.conf seems to be strange: ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=... name=...   I expected /dev/md0

Comment: I don't know the exact reason behind this, but I'd say that's fine. I've just checked on a recently installed server in our company - it does say `/dev/md/0` in `mdadm.conf` too, but the RAID device is called `/dev/md0`. It probably has to do something with the 1.2 metadata.

Comment: Ok. no line "DEVICE": correct also ?

Comment: Yep, should be correct.

Comment: /boot/grub/device.map has a reference to my hdd "old system": shall I get rid that line ? (hd1) /dev/disk/by-id/ata-wdc...

Comment: I haven't found any explanation for `/dev/md/0` instead of `/dev/md0`, so I've posted a question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111479/linux-md-raid-dev-md0-vs-dev-md-0

Comment: @Bertaud yes, I usually delete those. It probably won't do any harm though.

Comment: In /etc/fstab, after a blkid, shall I write /dev/md0: UUID=... or/and each lines /dev/mapper/myRaid-root: UUID= ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12730/discussion-between-martin-von-wittich-and-bertaud)

Comment: just tell me how to answer to your questions in the chat !