# Linux md RAID: /dev/md0 vs. /dev/md/0

Tags: debian, mdadm, md

On newer systems `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf` (the script that is used to generate `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`) tends to use the device name `/dev/md/0` instead of `/dev/md0`:

```
new-system ~ # /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf | grep ARRAY
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=a0021927:0e4f10bf:2c47dc72:ca0b352e name=unassigned:0
```

This may cause some irritation for users who expect `/dev/md0` there, but apparently it works fine because the server boots without problems.

In `/proc/mdstat` the device is still called `/dev/md0`:

```
new-system ~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[2] sda2[0]
      1953381184 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

`ls` shows that `/dev/md/0` is a symlink to `/dev/md0`:

```
new-system ~ # ls -l /dev/md/0 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Nov 20 14:06 /dev/md/0 -> ../md0
```

On another older system `mkconf` still uses `/dev/md0` instead, and `/dev/md` is empty:

```
old-system ~ # /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf | grep ARRAY
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=76472cf5:83fd8e5a:ad617046:69b2ebf1
old-system ~ # ls -l /dev/md
total 0
```

I'd like to know the difference between these device names, and I can't find any explanation on Google. Is `/dev/mdN` the old name, and `md` is planning to move to `/dev/md/N` device names? Is this change related to the 1.2 metadata (I've noticed that the new server is using md 1.2, while the old one is still using 0.90)?

---

EDIT 2017-09-11: I think [Krzysztof Stasiak's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374983/32931) is the correct one. I had by now totally forgotten about this question. While playing with a test RAID last friday I thought "why not name my array instead of memorizing what md0, md1, md2, ... etc. does in complex setups?", and so I tried:

```
test-server ~ # mdadm --assemble /dev/mdfoobar /dev/loop[01]
mdadm: /dev/mdfoobar is an invalid name for an md device.  Try /dev/md/mdfoobar
```

And indeed that works:

```
test-server ~ # mdadm --assemble /dev/md/foobar /dev/loop[01]
mdadm: /dev/md/foobar has been started with 2 drives.

test-server ~ # ll /dev/md/foobar 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Sep 11 10:45 /dev/md/foobar -> ../md0

test-server ~ # cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 loop0[0] loop1[1]
      102272 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

(You can also do `mdadm --assemble foobar DEV...`).

There's a detailed explanation in `man mdadm`, section `DEVICE NAMES`.

Comment: https://lkml.org/lkml/2002/11/19/342

Comment: @frostschutz ah, so the array name from `mdadm -E` that is currently `unassigned:0` on the new server is split at the `:`, and the second part becomes part of the `/dev/md/<name>`? So if I'd change the array name to `unassigned:asdf`, the symlink would be called `/dev/md/asdf`? And the actual device is always called `/dev/mdN`, where N is the next free number?

Comment: You could use it that way, but nobody does it; it doesn't really work, since usually the md is created from a live cd that does not have your host name set, etc. A name like `unassigned:0` is just braindead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can name array as own name (not only 0-127) and since mdadm 3.0.3 you can use only name. If think path was changed to use subfolder `/dev/md/$name` to make more flexibility or some kind of clean or group arrays.
If md array is created in format `/dev/mdX` there is added symlink to make compability to new format.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to device names, better ask [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev). To my understanding,

1. `md%d` naming is used by kernel, it is generated directly by driver [md.c#L5646](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/md/md.c#L5646), and it's used in `/proc/partitions` and `sysfs`. Hence, it appears in `/dev`
2. `/dev/md/...` and `/dev/disk/by-id/...` are generated as symlinks by udevd. In my system corresponding rules are kept in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/63-md-raid-arrays.rules`:

   ```
   ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{MD_DEVNAME}=="?*", SYMLINK+="md/$env{MD_DEVNAME}"
   ```

It seems that udev file comes from `openSUSE 11.1-rc3` according to [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/mdadm/mdadm.git/commit/udev-md-raid.rules?id=757a5d74ff11aadb87c9ff8e038c7140d2c457a8) in mdadm. I've checked this file in `openSUSE 11.0`, but it doesn't have `md/%d` symlinks...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the original path varies depending on the Linux kernel version or Unix system. The symbolic link `/dev/md/N` may exist for compatibility reasons. Programs or scripts that may use this path instead of `/dev/mdN`.